# What does the phrase 'make the girls tick' mean?

Tags: american-english

I read the following phrase in a dating book.

> find out who they are and what made them tick?

What does the phrase *make the girls tick* mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The phrase is "[what makes one tick](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/what+makes+tick)"

> what makes someone tick
>
> Fig. something that motivates someone; something that makes someone
>   behave in a certain way.

In your dating context it implies you should *not* just know the person superficially but also get to know what that person is interested in, what motivates them, what are their likes and dislikes - and that will help you have a better relationship.

I imagine the origin of the idiom will be from knowing the internal machinery which makes a clock tick.

Comment: The imagery of clockwork is important to the phrase; if you have ever taken a clock apart to find out what makes it tick, you will appreciate how complex and challenging it is when you try to reassemble it.

Comment: @Kit: *That* sir, I have not.

Comment: I would not recommend it then, neither with clocks nor with girls. :-)

Comment: @JoseK @Kit, the clock is a good way to understand this phrase, I was thinking the other way which probably wrong, what make the girl tick on her check list.