# Does British English have an equivalent of "under the hood"?

Tags: phrases

I feel like there must be some equivalent to the phrase "looking under the hood"in British English but have drawn a blank. Can anybody help?

Comment: Is 'looking under the hood' a metaphor or does it just refer to car-maintenance?

Comment: Sorry that the question was unclear. I mean as a metaphor for looking at how something works inside for example lets take a look under the hood of this piece of software

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are referring to what Americans call *the hood* of a car.

In Britain and in various other countries where English is spoken it is always called ***the bonnet***. And we ***look under the bonnet*** for exactly the same reasons that Americans *look under the hood*.

Comment: You are very right, but I very rarely hear British people say "look under the bonnet ". Am I just hanging out with the wrong crowd?

Comment: Is *behind the curtain* much found in BrE?

Comment: @bib, What does 'behind the curtain' mean -  is it a metaphor? Or do you literally mean something is behind a curtain in your house?  Note that 'looking under the bonnet' is literal - it means to examine the engine of your car.

Comment: @user145403 Surely most people have to look under the bonnet/hood at least to top up the screen-wash.  Or does your crowd have people to do that? (!)

Comment: [*Behind the curtain*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Behind+the+Curtain). See also, "The Wizard of Oz".

Comment: @user145403 It may not be used as much as it once was, simply because nowadays few people ever look under the bonnet of their car. They leave that to the garage which does the annual service. Modern cars do not breakdown or fail to start as was the case a few decades ago.

Comment: @DavidGarner The butler usually checks it for me ;-)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Surely that's the chauffeur's job?

Comment: We don't talk about the chauffer -- not after 'the incident'

Comment: There is also 'to look inside the box', but I couldn't say if it is particularly British, American or Australian.

Comment: @JohnMack I've never heard it used in Britain, as regards looking under the bonnet of a car.

Comment: @WS2 The OP indicated that cars, hoods and bonnets were all meant as metaphors.  To quote him/her: _'Sorry that the question was unclear. I mean as a metaphor for looking at how something works inside for example "Lets take a look under the hood of this piece of software".'_   This expands the concept somewhat.

Comment: 'Under the bonnet' would certainly be the BrEng equivalent but in the context of software/technology I have often read 'under the hood' - its meaning is perfectly clear to a British speaker.

Comment: @JohnMack I see nothing in the OP's question that it refers to cars, nor that it is metaphorical use that is being discussed. But certainly in Britain the term *under the bonnet* is widely used metaphorically, including by doctors and surgeons when pointing out to patients that they need to do exploratory work. *The scans reveal this..., but we shall not know for sure until we have taken a look under the bonnet*.

Comment: A variation on this I've heard is "drains up" which implies an in-depth investigatioin, often after something's gone wrong - the implication being opening manholes / inspecion covers (as in sewers / civil engineering) and investigating literally "under the surface"

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard much use of *under the bonnet* for the metaphorical use you ask about in your comment.  For this it's more common in the UK to say something like *get your hands dirty/mucky* (from farming/gardening).

This can mean to involve yourself in all parts of a job, including the parts that are unpleasant, or involve hard, practical work.  It can also be used to mean '*get stuck in there and see what's really going on here*' -

*Unlike other bosses, she's not afraid to get her hands dirty, and the staff like that.*

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+hands+dirty

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with the usage, *'Take a look inside the box'*, but I can't ascribe it to any particular version of English.  There is a variant on this, *'Think inside the box'*, which at first doesn't sound as clever or valuable as the more familiar, *'Thinking outside the box'*. But of course the point is that if you can't achieve or analyse anything in conventional terms ('Inside the box') you possibly aren't functioning particularly well, or well positioned to make useful observations *'Outside the box'*.

An alternative, and perhaps a more British one, is, *'To see what makes it tick'*, or *'Let's see what makes it tick'*.  This brings to mind an earlier question: [What does the phrase 'make the girls tick' mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34702).